# How to prepare an argument of type List<Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?>>

Tags: java, generics, guava, covariance

The objective is to write a convenience method that return a ResultSet from a JDBC query with a simple client-side invocation form.

I have written something like this:

```
public class JdbcQueryManager {
  public static ResultSet executePreparedStatementWithParameters(
      Connection jdbcConnection, String sqlQuery,
      Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?>... sqlQueryParameters)
      throws JdbcQueryFailureException {
    return executePreparedStatementWithParameters(jdbcConnection, sqlQuery,
        Arrays.asList(sqlQueryParameters), ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT);
  }
  private static ResultSet executePreparedStatementWithParameters(
      Connection jdbcConnection, String sqlQuery,
      List<Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?>> sqlQueryParameters,
      int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency, int resultSetHoldability)
      throws JdbcQueryFailureException {
    try {
      PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
          jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery, resultSetType,
              resultSetConcurrency, resultSetHoldability);
      for (int i = 0; i < sqlQueryParameters.size(); i++) {
        int sqlQueryParameterIndex = i + 1; // SQL parameters are 1-based
        Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?> sqlQueryParameter =
            sqlQueryParameters.get(i);
        Class<?> sqlQueryParameterClass = sqlQueryParameter.getKey();
        if (sqlQueryParameterClass == Integer.class) {
          int sqlQueryParameterIntegerValue =
              (Integer) sqlQueryParameter.getValue();
          preparedStatement.setInt(sqlQueryParameterIndex,
              sqlQueryParameterIntegerValue);
        } else if (sqlQueryParameterClass == String.class) {
          String sqlQueryParameterStringValue =
              (String) sqlQueryParameter.getValue();
          preparedStatement.setString(sqlQueryParameterIndex,
              sqlQueryParameterStringValue);
          // TODO: accept other types, not just String and Integer
        } else {
          throw new JdbcQueryFailureException(new IllegalArgumentException(
              sqlQueryParameterClass.getName()));
        }
      }
      ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      return resultSet;
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
      throw new JdbcQueryFailureException(sqlException);
    }
  }
}
```

using this convenience class:

```
public class QueryParameter<T> extends AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Class<T>, T> {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public QueryParameter(T parameterValue) {
    super((Class<T>) parameterValue.getClass(), parameterValue);
  }
}
```

to be able to execute a JDBC SQL statement like this:

```
ResultSet resultSet =
    JdbcQueryManager.executePreparedStatementWithParameters(jdbcConnection,
        sqlQuery, new QueryParameter<String>("AnswerRequest"),
        new QueryParameter<Integer>(42));
```

... how can I make it better?

Specifically, my perplexities lie in the use of this seemingly complicated, possibly unneeded form:

```
List<Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?>>
```

Comment: Side note: your formatter should accept at least 150 chars per line. This is typically the reason why, IMO.

Comment: The reason why... what? :) Do you mean "format code with more character per line" / "wider", basically?

Comment: IMHO, you're just complicating your life with the whole `QueryParameter` stuff. Why don't you use something like `execute(sqlQuery, "AnswerRequest", 42)` instead? I once wrote something like this and it works (with 4 different DBs).

Comment: You mean accepting an "Object... varargs" argument and just resorting to "for (Object o : varargs) preparedStatement.setObject(o)? I think this is what Bohemian recommended...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no value in passing in a list of `Map.Entry<? extends Class<?>, ?>` - you are attempting to tell your method what class each parameter is. **Don't do this!!!**

Contrary to popular belief, you don't need to use the various typed `preparedStatement.setXXX()` methods if you're using "basic" java objects (wrapped primitives and `Dates`), just use `preparedStatement.setObject(index, object)` and the jdbc driver will figure out what to do!

The only time you need to use a typed setter is if your object is *not* one of the "basic" types. If you really need this, then just use `instanceof` to check each parameter, then you'd write some code to maybe extract a String value to use, but you could still call `preparedStatement.setObject(index, object)` with that String.

I have written something like this myself and I simply used:

```
public static ResultSet executePreparedStatementWithParameters(
    Connection jdbcConnection, String sqlQuery, Object... parameters)
```

and it works just fine.

Comment: I looked at the source of a few JDBC drivers implementing setObject (e.g. Xerial's Sqlite, pgjdbc for PostreSQL, etc.) and most of them just do a series of instanceof checks (Timestamp, Double, Integer, Float. java.util.Date, etc.) before setting their type. You put a lot of emphasis in your "don't do this!!!" as if there was some harm in it, it's just redundant and thus introduces an unnecessary potential source of bugs, violating DRY due to duplication. Interesting you ended up doing something similar yourself, could you share the code?